# removing sign in option in power bi embedding in angular

Tags: angular, powerbi

This is vijay,can you please find out my image file inside my file in left side bar we have dashboard and power bi and some other icons, when i am click on power bi button right side the reports will be getting before that it is asking sign in option from power bi client side no need to sign in when client click on the power bi directly will get reports.i am implementing this source code in angular is there any possible to avoid sign in option can u give me suggestion please.
thanks and regards
vijay

[image]

Comment: You mixed up [Publish to web (public)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web) and [(secure) Embed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-embed-secure). Secure embed **requres** users to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the token in the server-side and get the response carrying report-id, emebed-token and embed URL in client-side. The authentication will be handled by the server-side code and embedding will be handled in the client-side.